# log4net in .NET core 6

Tags: c#, log4net, .net-6.0

I used to use .NET core 5, but now I'm trying to use .NET core 6, it seems the old `Startup.cs` is mixed now with `Program.cs`.

The thing is that I'm trying to add log4net to my project, and it gives me an error I'm not sure what is happening or I'm missing something. The error says:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'ILoggingBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddLog4Net' and no accessible extension method 'AddLog4Net' accepting a first argument of type 'ILoggingBuilder' could be found
```

I have installed log4net via Nuget Managment and Package Manager Console Nothing seems to work, here is a part of my `Program.cs` file:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Logging.AddLog4Net(); // <-- here is where I got the error

// Add services to the container.
var services = builder.Services;
services.AddCors();
services.AddControllers();

services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
services.AddSwaggerGen();
services.AddLogging();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `log4net` instead of the arguably more standard `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`? Apparently `log4net` [hasn't been significantly updated since 2017](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/#versions-tab) (the 6 most recent updates were point-releases), and it only targets/supports .NET Standard 1.3 which is equally ancient - so it doesn't support any of the stuff added since after .NET Core 1, basically.

Comment: @Dai I chose `log4net` because I used to use in all my previous projects, now I can see what you mean, I think is a better option to choose a most recently updated one, thanks.

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` does not support logging to file, and Microsoft suggests using a third party library, like log4net. Maybe Serilog or Nlog are better updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a separate extension package to make it work in most use cases.

The package you need is:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore/

Documentation and source:
https://github.com/huorswords/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Remeber to use `using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;` in your startup class or similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use similar like below:

```
builder.Host.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                              {
                                  logging.AddLog4Net(log4NetConfigFile: "log4net.config");
                                  logging.ClearProviders();
                                  logging.AddConsole();//for Logging on Console 
                                  logging.AddLog4Net();//for DB Query Logging
                              });
```